# mvn -x switch within pom.xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven, jenkins

I am running a build on Jenkins, I would like to enable -x switch so I can do some debugging. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dqsalpha-dev.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>dqsalpha</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1001</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <executions>
                    <execution><!-- Run our version calculation script -->
                        <id>Version Calculation</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${basedir}/@test.sh</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

is there a way to enable the -X switch with the pom file?

Or perhaps, I can add the -X switch to the Jenkins configuration, which looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to update the `Goals and options` field in Jenkins to include the `-X` switch like so:

`-X clean install`

Comment: Thanks let me try that